# Dynamics DNS and VPN

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn

I have a few PCs/services that I want to access remotely, which are inside a VPN and gets assigned local IP addresses using DHCP.

How can I setup dynamic DNS to access the PCs on their internal VPN IP using a domain name eg. pc1.server.com?

**Progress:**

I tried using [www.noip.com](http://www.noip.com) to set up dynamic DNS, but how can I make the domain pc1.server.com point to an internal IP inside the VPN, eg 10.15.x.x instead of the public IP? If the PC trying to access it is not on the VPN this would not work obviously, but could it work if the PC trying to access it is in the VPN and thus can see the internal IP 10.15.x.x?

Answer (score 1):

The ddclient program can use many methods to find its IP, the common one is "web", it calls an external service to retrieve the public IP. It can use other methods that lead to the local IP (like "ip" or "if").

See the available options here:
https://sourceforge.net/p/ddclient/wiki/routers/

ddclient supports No-IP out of the box, and many other providers.

Or set static per-client IP in your VPN config, it would eliminate the overhead of dynamic IP.